# How to prevent useSearchBox() from querying Algolia data on initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, text, algolia

How do I prevent useSearchBox() from querying Algolia on initial render?

I do not want to query data until the user inputs a letter in the textfield.

Thank you!

Comment: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/conditional-requests/react/
https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/issues/1111

Comment: cool you can perhaps write an answer

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer in the Algolia docs thanks to @cmgchess by following the docs site. https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/conditional-requests/react/

```js
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite';
import { InstantSearch, SearchBox, Hits } from 'react-instantsearch';

const algoliaClient = algoliasearch(
  'YourApplicationID',
  'YourSearchOnlyAPIKey'
);

const searchClient = {
  ...algoliaClient,
  search(requests) {
    if (requests.every(({ params }) => !params.query)) {
      return Promise.resolve({
        results: requests.map(() => ({
          hits: [],
          nbHits: 0,
          nbPages: 0,
          page: 0,
          processingTimeMS: 0,
          hitsPerPage: 0,
          exhaustiveNbHits: false,
          query: '',
          params: '',
        })),
      });
    }

    return algoliaClient.search(requests);
  },
};

const App = () => (
  <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName="instant_search">
    <SearchBox />
    <Hits />
  </InstantSearch>
);
```